# Smart band for generating custom vibrations

Tags: linux, android, smart-watches, xiaomi-mi

I am looking for a low-cost smart band (should be available in India) which can be controlled from Linux machine and or Android app to generate custom vibrations.

**UPDATE**

I see that there are many smartbands available in tha market. Few of the provides sdk and most of them are costly as compared to those without any SDK. I have come across some bands like Xiomi Mi, Fitbit inspire which are low cost.

Comment: What research have you already done?

Comment: What’s your definition of “low cost”? How many do you need? What kind of connectivity do you need? What kind of battery life? Are you talking about a single prototype for a proof of concept or looking towards an actual deployment?

Comment: @jcaron This is for research purpose. PoC is enough.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Welcome to IoT Stack Exchange! Now answering your question...

*I really think you should make your own.*

All you would need is an NRF51/2, a cheap vibration motor (those are usually rated 3V/70mA), a transistor and some good ol' coding.

I researched a little bit about bracelets with vibration that can also be controlled with 3rd party apps and I got to a conclusion:

It might be **way** easier to develop your own.

Comment: If you want to build a single prototype to have fun, probably. If you need to deploy a few dozen/hundred of actually usable bands, probably not. If you are looking at developing a product with tens of thousands of bands to be made, yet another story.

Comment: @jcaron Since he said a PoC is enough, he should go for it. IMO, your comment is very right. For a prototype and product development, I dont think theres any good in buying it. But for a few dozen, for sure buying something is the recommended.